# JSSE wrap creates two tls packets requiring two unwraps. Why?

Tags: java, networking, ssl, openssl, jsse

I am inspecting the behavior of our java application with respect to jsse tls encryption and decryption with a connected openssl client.

First I observed that when I call unwrap for client data, it always unwraps consuming 37 bytes and producing 0. The next unwrap consumes some bytes and produces some.

At first I thought the client would wrap an empty array first.
But then I discovered that the jsse code does the same, except it produces 1 byte instead of 0.

So every call to a `wrap` consumes X bytes and produces Y bytes but requires TWO `unwrap`s while the first one consumes 37 bytes and produces 1 byte and the second one consumes Y-37 bytes and produces X-1 bytes.

While openssl and jsse are doing nearly the same, I expect that to be correct.
However I would like to know, why that happens. 
I don't see a reason for that and it takes additional resources...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is two slightly different ways of mitigating the BEAST attack. One way of doing this is to use [an empty fragment as it's done with OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/~bodo/tls-cbc.txt). The [JSSE does something similar by sending 1 byte of data and the rest separately](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/rev/0c65618b5ae1).

Here are a few links that may be of interest:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13534753/372643) to a similar question.
- [*Beat the BEAST with TLS 1.1/1.2 and More*](http://blogs.cisco.com/security/beat-the-beast-with-tls/).
- [*The BEAST summary - TLS, CBC, Countermeasures (Update 4)*](http://blog.zoller.lu/2011/09/beast-summary-tls-cbc-countermeasures.html).
- [*Tor and the BEAST SSL attack*](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-and-beast-ssl-attack).